# tuple index out of range for printing a index value

Tags: python-3.6

While executing the following code i'm getting below error, Just for information `matchObj` here returns a tuple value ..

```
$ ./ftpParser3_re_dup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ftpParser3_re_dup.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("{0:<30}{1:<20}{2:<50}{3:<15}".format("FTP ACCOUNT","Account Type","Term Flag"))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Code is below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
import re
with open('all_adta', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        data = f.read()
        # Making description & termflag optional in the regex pattern as it's missing in the "data_test" file with several occurrences.
        regex = (r"dn:(.*?)\nftpuser: (.*)\n(?:description:* (.*))?\n(?:termflag:* (.*))")
        matchObj = re.findall(regex, data)
        print("{0:<30}{1:<20}{2:<50}{3:<15}".format("FTP ACCOUNT","Account Type","Term Flag"))
        print("{0:<30}{1:<20}{2:<50}{3:<15}".format("-----------","------------","--------"))
        for index in matchObj:
            index_str = ' '.join(index)
            new_str = re.sub(r'[=,]', ' ', index_str)
            new_str = new_str.split()
            # In below print statement we are using "index[2]" as index is tuple here, this is because
            # findall() returns the matches as a list, However with groups, it returns it as a list of tuples.
            print("{0:<30}{1:<20}{2:<50}{3:<15}".format(new_str[1],new_str[8],index[2],index[3]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `print("{0:<30}{1:<20}{2:<50}{3:<15}".format("FTP ACCOUNT","Account Type","Term Flag"))` you have mentioned 4 indices but given only 3 i.e. `"FTP ACCOUNT","Account Type","Term Flag"`
Remove the 4th index or add a new one